# Cleaner way to do itertools product combination in Python?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have the following sample code. I'm prepending a mandatory '1' in front of the generated products. Is there a better way to do it using list generation without using `tuple([1]) + a`?

```
from itertools import product

print [tuple([1]) + a for a in list(product([0, 1], repeat=2))]
```

The output is:

```
[(1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Also, what's the best way to get the following result from the above output (Basically, multiplying each value in the tuple by `10^i` where `i` is in respective index and summing that result):

```
[100, 101, 110, 111]
```

Comment: What is the overall goal of this code? It looks like you're doing some binary manipulations, and there may be a better way to do it with other datatypes or methods.

Comment: why are you calling list on the product? You are creating two copies of the data. also how is `111` the result?

Comment: The goal is to create valid numbers which are only made out 1s and 0s. In this case the numbers have 3 digits (repeat + 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def rawProducts(repeat=2):
  return product([0, 1], repeat=repeat)

def toNumber(seq):
  # here's the trick: the last parameter to reduce() is the initial value;
  # we pretend that we already have a 1 before we started iterating 
  # over seq, instead of prepending the 1 to seq.
  return reduce(lambda acc, x: 10 * acc + x, seq, 1)

result = [toNumber(prod) for prod in rawProducts()]
```

Will this work for you? BTW works for different values of `repeat` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`tuple([1])` is equivalent to just `(1,)`, and you don't need to call `list`:

```
print [(1,) + a for a in product([0, 1], repeat=2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
map(int,("".join(("1",)+x) for x in list(product("01", repeat=2))))
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd first create a helper function to handle the numeric joining.

```
def num_join(*digits):
    return int(''.join(map(str, digits)))
```

Then just use that in a simplified version of your list comprehension

```
print [num_join(1, *a) for a in product((0, 1), repeat=2)]
```

The technique I use to transform a tuple of digits into a number is to simply cast each digit to a string so I can use ordinary string joining, then cast it back into an int. I also remove the redundant `list`, which is not necessary when we're iterating over the result of `product` anyway.

Comment: If someone finds this answer awful enough to warrant voting it down, it would be nice to have some feedback along with it.

Comment: I'd like to avoid having it converted to a string then an int. I didn't downvote this though.